# Search for a value in nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have to check if an object contains a value in javascript and I don't know how to do it. The object looks like this:

```
Match {
  player1: undefined,
  player2: undefined,
  childrenLeft: 
   Match {
     player1: 'John',
     player2: 'Mary',
     childrenLeft: undefined,
     childrenRight: undefined },
  childrenRight: 
   Match {
     player1: 'Michael',
     player2: 'James',
     childrenLeft: undefined,
     childrenRight: undefined }
  }
```

Now it's a competition with a final and two semi-finals but it could be much bigger depending on the number of players so I need to traverse all the tree. 
I have this function that supposes to return the next opponent but it doesn't work when I search for players on the childrenLeft. So, when I execute Match.nextOpponent(James) I got 'Michael' as a result but when I execute Match.nextOpponent(Mary) I got 'undefined'.

```
Match.prototype.nextOpponent = function (player) {
    if (this.player1 === player) return this.player2;
    if (this.player2 === player) return this.player1;
    if (!this.player2 && !this.player1 && this.childrenRight !== undefined) return this.childrenRight.nextOpponent(player);
    if (!this.player1 && !this.player2 && this.childrenLeft !== undefined) return this.childrenLeft.nextOpponent(player);
}
```

Anyone could help? 
Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your object structure is not clear. Do you have an array with multiple `Match` objects? But from your question it appears that you have nested `Match` obhects. Your description doesn't show the structure of your objects at all; it's just some lines of text.

Comment: _it doesn't work_ prevents anyone else from helping you with your problem. What did you expect to happen, and what actually did happen?

Comment: Thank's for the reply, now I edited my massage and I think it's more clear. I have a competition where each match is an object and I need to find who will be the next opponent. So the whole structure is a binary tree. In the example above is simple but could be much bigger depending on the size of the tournament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you `return` in the last two `if` blocks, even when the return value from the recursive call is `undefined`. This means that if the first `if` condition is true, there is no way that the second `if` condition is even tried.

So to resolve this, use this code:

```
Match.prototype.nextOpponent = function (player) {
    if (this.player1 === player) return this.player2;
    if (this.player2 === player) return this.player1;
    var match;
    if (!this.player2 && !this.player1 && this.childrenRight) 
        match = this.childrenRight.nextOpponent(player);
    // maybe previous return value was undefined, then try the other side:
    if (!match && !this.player1 && !this.player2 && this.childrenLeft) 
        match = this.childrenLeft.nextOpponent(player);
    return match;
}
```

```js
function Match(p1, p2) {
    this.player1 = p1;
    this.player2 = p2;
    this.childrenLeft = undefined;
    this.childrenRight = undefined;
}

Match.prototype.nextOpponent = function (player) {
    if (this.player1 === player) return this.player2;
    if (this.player2 === player) return this.player1;
    var match;
    if (!this.player2 && !this.player1 && this.childrenRight) 
        match = this.childrenRight.nextOpponent(player);
    if (!match && !this.player1 && !this.player2 && this.childrenLeft) 
        match = this.childrenLeft.nextOpponent(player);
    return match;
}

var root = new Match();
root.childrenLeft = new Match('John', 'Mary'); 
root.childrenRight = new Match('Michael', 'James'); 

console.log('James plays: ', root.nextOpponent('James'));
console.log('Mary plays: ', root.nextOpponent('Mary'));
```

NB: you don't have to compare `childrenLeft` with `undefined`. As `undefined` is falsy and any object is truthy, you can just evaluate `childrenLeft` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Thank you so so soooo much! Now it works! Thank's for the explanations as well, very clear and understandable.

Comment: By the way, don't want to abuse but I posted another question related to this one, If you could have a look it would be great :) Thank's again